# сортировка по критерию

Tags: javascript, фильтрация

у меня есть n-ное количество карточек товара, с указанной внутри ценной, так же есть выпадающее меню с выбором критерия, как можно выстроить карточки в порядке убывания/возрастания по одному из критериев?

```js
function dropMenu() {
  let wind = document.querySelector('.select');
  let drop = document.querySelector('.select__drop');
  wind.onclick = () => {
    if (drop.style.display == "none") {
      drop.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      drop.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function selectPar() {
  let selected = document.querySelector('.select').querySelector('.selected');
  let elem = document.querySelector('.select__drop').querySelectorAll('.drop__selected');

  elem.forEach(el => {
    el.onclick = () => {
      selected.innerHTML = el.innerText;
    }
  })
}

dropMenu()
selectPar()
```

```css
.b {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 500px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.select {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  margin: 0px;
}

.select__drop {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: adsolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.drop__selected {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.drop__selected:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card" style="background:red;">
      <p class="card__title">
        Товар 1
      </p>
      <p class="card__price">
        1050
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="background:green;">
      <p class="card__title">
        Товар 2
      </p>
      <p class="card__price">
        1500
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="background:blue;">
      <p class="card__title">
        Товар 3
      </p>
      <p class="card__price">
        1000
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="background:grey;">
      <p class="card__title">
        Товар 4
      </p>
      <p class="card__price">
        5000
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="background:orange;">
      <p class="card__title">
        Товар 5
      </p>
      <p class="card__price">
        2000
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="background:yellow;">
      <p class="card__title">
        Товар 6
      </p>
      <p class="card__price">
        900
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="background:white;">
      <p class="card__title">
        Товар 7
      </p>
      <p class="card__price">
        1200
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="background:pink;">
      <p class="card__title">
        Товар 8
      </p>
      <p class="card__price">
        1500
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="select">
    <p class="selected">
      по умолчанию
    </p>
    <div class="select__drop" style="display: none;">
      <p class="drop__selected">
        по убыванию
      </p>
      <p class="drop__selected">
        по возрастанию
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: html возвращает сервер или есть json c товарами?

Comment: заранее прописанная вёрстка

Comment: тогда тот ответ который есть (я его тоже отметил), я писал свой ответ, но он по производительности в 2 раза медленнее.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, не подскажешь за что отвечают параметры `(a, b)` в `sort`? описание метода полистал, так и не понял как оно работает

Comment: это условно перебираемые элементы - a и b которые между собой сравниваются. Функция sort перебирает весь массив и закидывает 2 элемента в передаваемую функцию (первый и второй, второй и третий ... и т.д.) чтобы решить как их расположить относительно друг друга.

Comment: Почему бы `document.querySelector('.select').querySelector('.selected')` не сократить до `document.querySelector('.select .selected')`? Зачем лишние манипуляции с домом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверняка можно хранить данные в структуре и согласно им менять положение элементов. Но для наглядности сортирую массив с элементами `.card` согласно логике текущего `option`. Элементы отсортированного массив помещаю в собственный контейнер (где они и находятся) в установленном ранее порядке методом `.prepend()`. Так как одновременно на странице может существовать только один элемент, он не добавляется, а перемещается в начало контейнера.

Возможно, лучше будет использовать `.append()`, тогда надо просто поменять порядок сортировок на обратный.

При одинаковых значениях цены дополнительной проверки не проводит, можно по исходным номерам тогда располагать.

```js
const block = document.querySelector('.block');
const select = document.querySelector('select');

select.addEventListener('change', e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    let cards = [...block.querySelectorAll('.card')];
    
    switch(val){
        case 'по возрастанию':
            cards.sort((a,b) => {
                let priceA = +a.querySelector('.card__price').textContent;
                let priceB = +b.querySelector('.card__price').textContent;
                return priceB - priceA;
            })

            break;
        case 'по убыванию':
            cards.sort((a,b) => {
                let priceA = +a.querySelector('.card__price').textContent;
                let priceB = +b.querySelector('.card__price').textContent;
                return priceA - priceB;
            })
            break;
        case 'по умолчанию': 
            cards.sort((a,b) => {
                let titleA= +a.querySelector('.card__title').textContent.match(/\d+/)[0];
                let titleB = +b.querySelector('.card__title').textContent.match(/\d+/)[0];
                return titleB - titleA;
            })
            break;
    }
    cards.forEach(card => {
        block.prepend(card);
    })
})
```

```css
.b {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .block {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width: 500px;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  
  .card {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="b">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="card" style="background:red;">
        <p class="card__title">
          Товар 1
        </p>
        <p class="card__price">
          1050
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="background:green;">
        <p class="card__title">
          Товар 2
        </p>
        <p class="card__price">
          1500
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="background:blue;">
        <p class="card__title">
          Товар 3
        </p>
        <p class="card__price">
          1000
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="background:grey;">
        <p class="card__title">
          Товар 4
        </p>
        <p class="card__price">
          5000
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="background:orange;">
        <p class="card__title">
          Товар 5
        </p>
        <p class="card__price">
          2000
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="background:yellow;">
        <p class="card__title">
          Товар 6
        </p>
        <p class="card__price">
          900
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="background:white;">
        <p class="card__title">
          Товар 7
        </p>
        <p class="card__price">
          1200
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="background:pink;">
        <p class="card__title">
          Товар 8
        </p>
        <p class="card__price">
          1500
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <select style="position:fixed;top:10px;right:50px">
     <option selected>по умолчанию</option>
     <option>по возрастанию</option>
     <option>по убыванию</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: а что за `a` и `b` в `sort`? откуда оно взялось и какую функцию выполняет и как?